# MySQL Join Examining Every Row

Tags: mysql, join

This query on my site is taking a very long time to execute. I have a blog and a forum on my site that I have loosely integrated so every forum account has an account on the blog and vice versa. However the user_id's in each table aren't correlated so I have been joining them by username.

```
SELECT *
FROM comments AS c
INNER JOIN articles AS a ON c.article_id = a.article_id
INNER JOIN user_profiles AS p ON c.user_id = p.user_id
INNER JOIN blog_users AS b ON c.user_id = b.user_id
INNER JOIN forum_users AS f ON b.username = f.username
WHERE a.article_id =  :article_id
ORDER BY c.comment_id DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

When I used explain on the query I saw that the last join was examining every single row in the forum_users table to come up with the result which is over 1,000,000 rows. The username columns for both tables are indexed and all tables are InnoDB. As a workaround, I'm storing each user's forum user_id in the blog_users table, and vice versa so I can join directly on the user_id which has the query running much quicker but I would like to avoid having to do this if possible. Is there a way I could rework the query so the username join is more efficient?

Comment: Can you run an `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` on that query and post the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the table and column character sets the same? For example, blog_users in utf8 and forum_users in latin1? If they aren't the same, mysql won't use the indexes. You can change the character set with, for example:

`ALTER TABLE blog_users CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8`

If this is the problem, read the docs carefully before doing this. It can change the content of the columns. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

Comment: You were absolutely correct. MySQL was running CONVERT() on the 5,000,000 row table on every query which was making the query take forever. Changing both to the same charset fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Two things... Does your Comments table have an index on the Article ID... if not, get one... Second, your where clause is referring to the JOINED table of the query and not the primary table in your SELECT FROM...  Since they both have columns for article ID, I would change your where clause to

```
WHERE c.Article_ID = :article_ID
```

Additionally, ensure indexes on

user_profiles index on User_ID

blog_users index on User_ID

forum_users index on username